# Why the text goes a little up when comparing two minipages?

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I am trying to add a second name in the supervisor list and when I do it the list goes a little up compared with the Authors name. How can I do it to be in the same height:

[image: title page with and without second name in the supervisor list]

block code for the first and the second image:
first:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
{me}\\ 
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisors:} \\
{him}\\
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
```

second:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
{me}\\ 
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisors:} \\
{him}\\
her
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
```

Comment: `minipage` are vertically centred by default, use `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}` so they align on their top line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minipage` are vertically centred by default, use `[t]` for example

```
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
```

so they align on their top line